# Correct way to change default font in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, fonts, appearance

I had been enjoying Windows 8 for the last couple of months on my desktop and laptop, but now it seems MS did actually do something really stupid in this OS that bothers me. You can't change the default system font... Not via the control panel or other "regular" method anyway.

Looking it up on the net, I fount two possible ways, both involving registry edits.
One method changes a couple of registry keys in

> HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics

but they are in binary and so it seems weird to edit them. Also there are quite a few keys to edit.

Other tutorials change `MS Shell Dlg` and `Ms Shell Dlg 2` in

> HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes

Method 2 seems a lot easier but a lot of people also report it doesn't work.

Are there any more alternatives?

Comment: Have you tried either method?

Comment: @Ramhound no but what I'm trying to achieve seems to trivial that there must be some other way. Also I'd rather not start changing keys if they're the wrong ones.

Comment: I tried both methods from http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1175-fonts-change.html and confirmed they worked.  Windows 8.1 and Windows 8.0