# How to change the desktop icon font?

Tags: windows, fonts, windows-11, regedit

I am trying to change the font of the desktop icons. More specifically, I want to change it from Segoe UI to Rockwell Extra Bold.
As far as I know, the only way to do it is in regedit, but the font file is just binary.

[image: regedit screeshot]

[image]iconfont detail

Any way to change it? Preferably without any extra programs that I will have to install.
I am using Windows 11.

In case it wasn't clear, I only want to change the desktop icons font, not anything else.

Comment: it's not in a binary registry key ... I read an article about deleting the Segoe UI font filenames in registry, and then setting the substitute fonts ... one of the registry keys was HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes  .... the info is not very difficult to find

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing Windows 8 system font](https://superuser.com/questions/859392/changing-windows-8-system-font)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I solved it myself. It wasn't just the desktop icons but I think I like it better.

I created a .reg file and added these contents into it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Segoe UI (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Bold (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Bold Italic (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Italic (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Light (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Semibold (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Symbol (TrueType)"=""

 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]
"Segoe UI"="Rockwell Extra Bold"
```

I got it from [this](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-default-system-font-windows-10#:%7E:text=Copy%20and%20paste%20the%20following%20Registry%20code%20onto%20the%20file:) article.

Answer (score 1):

RegEdit allows you to modify binary data out of the box, so not sure where the problem lies.

Go to the key where you want to edit the value -> RMB on the value -> Modify binary data... -> Move to proper positions with mouse and/or arrow keys -> Backspace to delete -> Enter own characters

If the problem is in getting the value right, which you have not stated, then this answer should help, for instance: https://superuser.com/a/859430/1145698